# Find a value in a range (any of multiple column or rows) and return the value in far left most column of that row

Tags: excel, index-match

Looking for something like a typical index match formula that can look to the right and return value to the left, but look at *all* columns in a range. Take below valid formula for example.

(Excel 2021.)

Finds A1's value in column D, and it returns value from column C.

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$10,0))
```

In my ideal world I can Keep $D$1 and change $D$**10** to $F$10 so it searches all columns D/E/F, and still returns C like below. However that does not work in our real world, any other ideas please? Thanks!

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$F$10,0))
```

Update*
To clarify there are mix of letters and numbers. Also this table will be about 50k rows so hoping as simple as possible.

Also Column C will all be unique for sure, and D-F should be unique values but there is a chance a mistake and a few duplicates might be in.

Comment: Do you want to return (max) 1 value from each row, (max) 1 value from D1 to F10, or an array of all matches?

Comment: I have a simple formula if all values in D1:F10 are different numbers and Column C has only unique numbers.
`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$1:$D$10=A1) + ($E$1:$E$10=A1) + ($F$1:$F$10=A1), $C$1:$C$10)`

Comment: @okzoomer This will work but if OP has more columns in real sheet then he needs to add more and more or condition.

Comment: Thanks but the values are not all numbers, so this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need `MMUL()` with `INDEX()`. Try below formula if you have `Excel-365`.

```
=FILTER(C1:C10,MMULT(--(D1:F10=A1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D1:F1))))
```

For older version try

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$10,LARGE(MMULT(--($D$1:$F$10=A1),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1}))*ROW($C$1:$C$10),1))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Do you think it will be viable to run daily for 50k rows (i5 processor)? Guess  I'll find out later this week. Thank you so much.

Comment: Will not issue for 50K row.

Answer (score 1):

Since your INDEX/MATCH take from the same rows, you can first simplify your original search with

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$D$10,$C$1:$C$10)
```

`XLOOKUP` combines `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` with exact match being the default.

This will work for searching three rows

```
IFERROR(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$D$10,$C$1:$C$10), XLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$E$10,$C$1:$C$10)), XLOOKUP(A1,$F$1:$F$10,$C$1:$C$10))
```

We can name the columns `colC`, `colD`, `colE`, and `colF` and it becomes

```
IFERROR(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A1,colD,colC), XLOOKUP(A1,colE,colC)), XLOOKUP(A1,colF,colC))
```

As with other lookups, this returns the first value or `#N/A` error.

This could be made more scalable for higher number of rows if we are allowed to add a column somewhere.

Comment: This did work as well, with 50k rows though I am not sure which will run smoother but will test. Thanks!